# Pythonic way of copying values in an array with a complex rule

Tags: python

If the value in column `a` is 1 then the value of `b` is copied in column `c` until `a` is -1.

In the example below, `a` is 1 in row 2 and -1 in row 5. Then the second value in column `b` (13) is copied in column `c` from row 2 to 5.

```
row a   b   c
1   0  12   0
2   1  13  13
3   0  15  13
4   0   2  13
5  -1  19  13
6   0  34   0
7   0  11   0
8   1  23  23
9   0  14  23
10 -1   9  23
11  0  18   0
12  0  19   0
```

I've done this with a for loop, but there must be a more elegant way to do this manipulating series (I'm using pandas, numpy). All your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: I tried implementing it as a for loop and my result seems pretty elegant (assuming a 2D array). It only visits each row once and has a worst-case of 4 operations per row. Like @BrendanLong suggested, if you post your code we can help you optimize it, otherwise we have no way of knowing what your problem with your current approach is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that does use a `for` loop but is pretty succinct while still being understandable.

I'm assuming you have the data stored in `table`, with `a` as `table[:,0]` and that `a` always appears as (1, -1)*, with 0 interspersed.

```
 starts = table[:,0] == 1
 ends = table[:,0] == -1
 for start, end in zip(starts.nonzero()[0], ends.nonzero()[0]):
     table[start:end+1,2] = table[start,1]
```

I bet there's some fancy way to get rid of that loop, but I'd also bet that it's harder to tell what's going on.

I agree with everyone else that if you post what you currently have it'd help to go from there.